# Setting time ticks in a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, formatting, matlab-figure

On the x-axis of my plot should be the time and on the y-axis the value. For each value I have a time stamp in milliseconds. I would like to have on the x-axis a tick every say 5 minutes, say 16:05, 16:10, 16:15 and so on. The time distance between the values is not equal.

How can this be done?

An example of a data vector is (first column timestamp, second column value):

```
27634517312999, 1.1111809015274048
27658503234656, 0.7998865246772766
27662988099446  0.7806665897369385
27664499628612  0.7781039476394653
27950691973920  0.8562135696411133
27970195902662  0.8036822080612183
27973194252661  0.7908696532249451
....
```

I think I have to be more clear. Each value has an assigned absolute timestamp in milliseconds which represents the time elapsed from 1970 (I think). I have gathered this values by `System.currentTimeMillis()` call from Java. For example 27658503234656 corresponds to Mon Jun 18 2846 14:33:54 GMT+0100. The values span rougly a range of one hour (the same year, day etc.). That means the first timestamp is 27658501657000 (representing Mon Jun 18 2846 14:07:37 GMT+0100) and the last timestamp is 27658504995000 (representing Mon Jun 18 2846 15:03:15 GMT+0100). I'm only interested in 14:07 until 15:03. On my x-axis the first label should be at 14:10 and then there should be labels every 5 min, i.e. 14:15, 14:20 etc. The last label is at 15:00.

How can this be done?

Comment: Updating your question does not make either the duplicates, or the answers invalid. Read about the `datenum` I mentioned in my answer for your first step. Seeing you don't even mention a single MATLAB function I presume you don't even know any of that, so going through the basics of that might help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer by Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45818396/5211833) using `datetick` should be the easy solution. If you like to control the level of detail by yourself, you could do something like:

```
% suppose data is your matrix (n x 2)
t = data(:,1) / 1000 / 3600 / 24; % time from ms to days
plot(t, data(:,2), '+-');
ticks = linspace(min(t), max(t), 5); % 5 ticks from min to max
labels = datestr(ticks, 'HH:MM'); % get only hours and minutes
set(gca, 'xtick', ticks, 'xtickLabel', labels);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for ticks = linspace(min(t), max(t), 5); saying that "Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles." It is perhaps because my timestamps are in int64. But converting to int32 or int16 did not solve the problem.

Comment: Since you will convert that into days, so you should cast it into double by double(t).

Comment: Actually I don't want to convert into days but into hours and minutes...

Comment: Still it is better cast into double, although it may increase the memory usage. Integer types can sometimes have weird result if not dealt correctly.

Comment: By the way t = data(:,1) / 1000 / 3600 / 24; does not work because it just gives me the day, i.e. all timestamps are afterwards 17397 (i.e. the same day) and datestr then just gives me 00:00.

Comment: By the way, the milliseconds measurement are absolute measurements for example 27658503234656 represents Mon Jun 18 2846 14:33:54 GMT+0100.

Comment: If you cast the ms into double, the result won't integer anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`datetick`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html?s_tid=doc_ta)

```
dateFormat = 15; % 15 is HH:MM, see docs
datetick('x',dateFormat)% equivalent: datetick('x','HH:MM')
```

If you need specific boundaries on your axis, you can use [`xlim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html?s_tid=doc_ta) to set the precise boundary you require. If you also need help converting your millisecond value into a proper date, divide by `1e3`, since I suspect they are already in [`datenum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?s_tid=doc_ta) format.